# using JavaScript object syntax or jquery code to create class members that are classes themselves 

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have something along the following lines:

```
var Class1=function(p1,p2){
   //ctor code
}
Class1.prototype={

   method:function(){...},
   method:function(){...}
}
```

I want Class2 to be a member of Class1
so that I could write:

```
instance2=new Class1.Class2(...)
```

or within methods of Class1 I could write:

```
this.instanceOfClass2=new this.Class2(...);
```

I know I can just add:

```
Class1.prototype={
              ...,
              Class2:function() {
              }
}
Class1.prototype.Class2.prototype={
    //Class2 methods go here
}
```

but this syntax has a disadvantage in that it places the methods of Class2 "far" from the constructor.

I could create a `Class(ctor,methods)` constructor and then use

```
Class1.prototype={
              ...,
              Class2:Class(function() {
                             //Class2 ctor
                           },
                           {
                             //Class2 methods go here
                           }
                     }     

}
```

but was wandering if there is a better way to do this.

My Thanks to everyone that commented on inaccuracy of terms use in original version of the Q.

Comment: I have a feeling that jQuery probably is not the best library to go with for doing Prototypal OOP in javascript.

Comment: my (now restored) original subject did not specifically refer to jQuery.
I was more hopeing for a syntax I might not be aware of. something like `{ class2:ctor,class.prototype:{methods}}` (which does not work...)

Comment: JSON is a data format. It doesn't do classes or functions and can't have anything to do with this question.

Comment: sorry to have pissed you off @Quentin, I am aware of JSON being a data format. in "strict" JOSN you could not have {a:function(){}} at all. but when writing code in javascript using this "object notation". you can. how would you call this syntax?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you misunderstood the fundamental principles of subclassing. A subclass is per definition not another class attached to the parent object, more like a class that inherits the parent class.

Consider this:

```
Class1 = function() {
  // constructor
}

Class1.prototype = {
  constructor: Class1,
  method1: function() {
    // public method
  }
};

Class2 = function() {
  //subclass constructor
}

Class2.prototype = new Class1(); // this is where the inheritance happens

var instance = new Class2();
instance.method1();
```

This is the "classic" way of handling subclassing/OOP in javascript. I’m not sure this helps, but it might be useful to know.

Comment: You are right. I am using the wrong term here. My Question is about class members that are classes themselves. I will edit the Q to reflect this. Is there a good short name for this?